# Instagram - access_token constantly expiring

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, instagram

I have an Instagram feed on a site which fetches the latest 25 posts of their IG account. This is done with a basic jsonp request, using the standard `api.instagram.com` call. Nothing too exciting or ground breaking.

While the site's been in development, the access_token expired 3 times. I should have really heeded those warning signs. Since the site's gone live, it expired 4 times yesterday alone.

I know in the docs it tells me not to assume the token lasts forever, but surely they don't define "forever" as 2 months?

What theoretically could be causing the `access_token` to expire so often? My only idea is that they're using Juicer (a 3rd party social aggregation service) which could be hammering the API?

I also thought because the app was still in sandbox it would have tighter restrictions. That can't be the case because when I try to submit it for approval, I get denied:

> If you are a developer and you want to display Instagram content on your website, then you do not need to submit your app for review. By using a client in sandbox mode, you can still access the last **20** media of any sandbox user that grants you permission.

(Surely I'm not getting penalized because I'm requesting 25?)

All out of ideas otherwise. Am I doing anything inherently wrong or is this just Instagram being exceedingly strict?

All help appreciated,
Tom

Comment: Two month seems reasonable; especially considering it is the same value Facebook (who own Instragram) use for their extended user tokens …

Comment: Yeah 2 months is fair enough. But it's actually expired 4 times within 2 days. There's surely something interfering with it? 

Contacted Instagram as well, but never in a month of Sundays will I expect them to reply!

Comment: It definitely seems like the tokens are expiring more frequently. But it only seems to happen to some users where the tokens expire multiple times per day. Could it be that they are logging in from different devices or locations frequently?

Comment: my guess is its cause you are in sandbox mode, I have used live mode API and the `access_token` has never expired in almost a year, before the API changes I was able to use same `access_token` for over a year.

Comment: @krisrak, ok, I might try submitting it for approval and see what happens.

Comment: @krisrak, Problem is, I can't get it to approve since "You do not need to submit for review for this use case". If I try submitting using the case "My product helps brands and advertisers understand, manage their audience and media rights.", I need to provide a videocast url. 

I'm currently between a rock and a hard place with this. The restrictions are very badly documented and I really don't know what to do now.